# Do I create a deadlock for Task.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, deadlock

I seem to be experiencing a deadlock with the following code, but I do not understand why.
From a certain point in code I call this method.

```
public async Task<SearchResult> Search(SearchData searchData)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<FolderResult>>();

    using (var serviceClient = new Service.ServiceClient())
    {
        foreach (var result in MethodThatCallsWebservice(serviceClient, config, searchData))
                tasks.Add(result);
        return await GetResult(tasks);
    }
```

Where GetResult is as following:

```
private static async Task<SearchResult> GetResult(IEnumerable<Task<FolderResult>> tasks)
{
    var result = new SearchResult();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    foreach (var taskResult in tasks.Select(p => p.MyResult))
    {
        foreach (var folder in taskResult.Result)
        {
            // Do stuff to fill result
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The line `var result = new SearchResult();` never completes, though the GUI is responsive because of the following code:

```
    public async void DisplaySearchResult(Task<SearchResult> searchResult)
    {
        var result = await searchResult;
        FillResultView(result);
    }
```

This method is called via an event handler that called the Search method.

```
_view.Search += (sender, args) => _view.DisplaySearchResult(_model.Search(args.Value));
```

The first line of `DisplaySearchResult` gets called, which follows the path down to the GetResult method with the `Task.WhenAll(...)` part.

**Why isn't the `Task.WhenAll(...)` ever completed? Did I not understand the use of await correctly?**
If I run the tasks synchronously, I do get the result but then the GUI freezes:

```
foreach (var task in tasks)
    task.RunSynchronously();
```

I read various solutions, but most were in combination with `Task.WaitAll()` and therefore did not help much. I also tried to use the help from [this blogpost](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) as you can see in `DisplaySearchResult` but I failed to get it to work.

Update 1:
The method `MethodThatCallsWebservice`:

```
private IEnumerable<Task<FolderResult>> MethodThatCallsWebservice(ServiceClient serviceClient, SearchData searchData)
{
    // Doing stuff here to determine keys
   foreach(var key in keys)
        yield return new Task<FolderResult>(() => new FolderResult(key, serviceClient.GetStuff(input))); // NOTE: This is not the async variant
}
```

Comment: Why are you using .ConfigureAwait(false); only once ? You can use it 1 time more. Assuming that FillResultview is updating GUI elements.

Comment: There's no obvious reason for your code to block. Is `ServiceClient` thread-safe?

Comment: Why `tasks` variable is of type `ConcurrentBag` when no concurrency involved? Can you post a short but complete program to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What is MethodThatCallsWebservice?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck FillResultview does indeed update GUI elements. Where would I use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` one more time?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That is some old stuff from a previous try, I'll try to get a smaller version.

Comment: @NedStoyanov I added the method, note that there is a async method available. I decided to not call that one because I would get nested tasks.

Comment: return await GetResult(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Ah, right! I tried it, but didn't help a thing :(.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid You meant that there's `GetStuffAsync`?

Comment: Yes, that method is available, but it doesn't seem to be any different if I await that task in GetResult too.

Comment: @i3arnon I have no clue. Got any idea on how to check that out? The developer that created the service isn't at the office at the moment.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid you said " I added the method, note that there is a async method available. I decided to not call that one because I would get nested tasks" and in the code "// NOTE: This is not the async variant". What does that mean?

Comment: @i3arnon That the async method is available but I did not use it at the moment of writing this question. I tried it before but at the moment it made zero difference.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid so there is `GetStuffAsync` which you  are not using. It made zero difference in what?

Comment: @i3arnon it made zero difference because I never started the task before the await statement. (see the accepted answer)

Comment: @Mixxiphoid it makes a lot of difference because: 1. You don't need to start if if it's coming from an `async` method. 2. Using the `async` version is much better than wasting threads on the synchronous one. See my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an asynchronous version of `GetStuff` (`GetStuffAsync`) it's much better to use it instead of offloading the synchronous `GetStuff` to a `ThreadPool` thread with `Task.Run`. This wastes threads and limits scalability.

`async` methods return a "hot" task so you don't need to call `Start`:

```
IEnumerable<Task<FolderResult>> MethodThatCallsWebservice(ServiceClient serviceClient, SearchData searchData)
{
    return keys.Select(async key => 
        new FolderResult(key, await serviceClient.GetStuffAsync(input)));
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I understand now. This all looks so much simpler now, thanks a lot. This also reduces the nested task thing I had :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your tasks before you return them. Or even better use Task.Run.

This:

```
    yield return new Task<FolderResult>(() => 
                 new FolderResult(key, serviceClient.GetStuff(input))) 
                // NOTE: This is not the async variant
```

Is better written as:

```
yield return Task.Run<FolderResult>(() => 
             new FolderResult(key, serviceClient.GetStuff(input)));
```

Comment: And how will I do that when it is wrapped in a class? And why is Task.Run better?

Comment: Task.Run creates and starts the task in one and it doesn't have the synchronization penalty that Task.Start() has

Comment: This link might help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: It did help a little, it doesn't hang anymore on `Task.WhenAll()` but now there is a no data to display, as if the service method was never called. I now try to call the Async version and now it is hanging on the await of the async method result...

Comment: I finally got it working now. I'll post the final changes in my question. The Task.Run certainly made a change, thanks a lot.